# refactoring multiple variable names intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there any way for Intellij to refactor the code consisting of multiple copy-pasted lines like this one:

```
Comment a1 = new Comment(1,null);
Comment a1 = new Comment(1,null);
Comment a1 = new Comment(1,null);
... and
.. so
. on
```

into

```
Comment a1 = new Comment(1,null);
Comment a2 = new Comment(1,null);
Comment a3 = new Comment(1,null);
... and
.. so
. on
```

Comment: The former isn't valid code, right?  And in either case, have you considered using an array instead?

Comment: Yes, it obviously is not valid, and I have to use such silly construction, because all the nulls in the constructors are really meant for references to other(parent) Comments.

Comment: The correct answer is no, but that's not entirely true. It's not really necessary because this is such a silly thing to do that nobody has ever bothered to request a feature to do it.

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing to do that would be [Shifter plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6149?pr=idea). It can increment the number in a variable under the caret ([and more in the future](https://github.com/kstenschke/shifter-plugin/issues/14#issuecomment-100893555)).

Or [String Manipulation plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/2162?pr=idea) which can duplicate and increment numbers inside of the selected text, making:

```
Comment a1 = new Comment(1, null);
```

into

```
Comment a1 = new Comment(1, null);
Comment a2 = new Comment(2, null);
```

or just increment all numbers in a selection, or on a line with a caret.